# When loading a CSV file into HBase by using Pig, is it possible to ignore columns from the CSV file?

Tags: csv, hbase, apache-pig

I need to ignore a few columns from a CSV file when loading them into HBase using Apache Pig.

Example CSV file:

```
No,Name,City
1,a,ny
2,b,la
3,c,chi
```

Can I load only the `No` and `City` into HBase while ignoring the `Name`?

Comment: Yes,you can.What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried concat into seperate var in PIG and then load it into HBASE. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

```
raw_data = LOAD 'hdfs//Sample.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (No:int,Name:chararray,City:chararray);
selected_data = FOREACH raw_data GENERATE $0 as No,$2 as City;

STORE selected_data INTO 'hbase://YourTable' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('YourTable:City');
```

Comment: what is $1 for selected_data? what happens if i make it as
selected_data=FOREACH raw_data GENERATE $0 as No, $1 as City;

Comment: ahh nvm, I guess that $ is referencing the position in the raw_data and not selected_data, right?

Comment: Yes, selected_data contains data from 1(i.e $0) & 3(i.e.$2) columns of raw_data